# How to run jardesc file from the command line?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jardesc file to build jar file, I want to run it from the command line for convenience.

Comment: Do your packaging with Maven instead if you want automation. Eclipse obviously isn't a command-line tool.

Comment: Thank you,  millimoose. I gotta learn Maven then.